# KDE Software Development kit

Tags: kde

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, with GNOME, I keep getting a message saying "software update available" for KDE Software Development kit.  However, clicking on the update button results in an "Unable to update software" message.  This happens every day after I turn the computer on in the morning. I am not sure why I should get this update notice in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, too. It went away after I opened a terminal and ran:

```
sudo apt install kdesdk
sudo apt-get update
```

I regret to say that I don't know *why* this cycle started. Perhaps hunting around here: [linuxappfinder.com/package/kdesdk](https://linuxappfinder.com/package/kdesdk) will reveal something.